# What type and thickness glass should I use in picture frames?

Tags: framing

I'm building a picture frame and am wondering what type and size glass I should use? The frame will be 16x20", maybe bigger, so I think I want a fairly thick glass. Would 1/8" be sufficient? Regular plate glass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single strength (3/32) is the standard for picture frames, but I'd start thinking Double strength (1/8) at 16x20 or larger.  1/8 is the standard for cabinet doors, so it will be more than adequate for a picture frame.

Answer (score 0):

I use archival non glare glass 3/32, i buy in bulk and cut it to my dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

The thickness of 3 mm is quite enough. The thicker it gets heavier which probably could create a problem; especially in big frames. In big frames (width bigger than >100 cm) the frame tends to bend because of the weight of glass and frame itself.
You may want to support your frame in the bottom line with carefullyy hided topless nails.
And the quality of glass for frames? It depends on how much you want to afford. Please take a took at this link: http://www.frameusa.com/blog/what-are-the-different-types-of-picture-framing-glass/